# allow torrent download iptable

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables, torrent

efw(endian firewall) by default close p2p traffic, to enable that i open all 1024:65535 ports. its work, but it's a bad solution.

i try open 6881:7000 & 2710 also client selected port but it's not working.

is any other better solution?

Comment: Since it works with the more permisive rule just run tcpdump and see what is actually being used.

Answer (score 2):

Bittorent clients don't necessarily always use the same port, but they generally only use one port at a time. Pick a port, any port, and tell your client to use it always, and then just open that one port.

Note that not only do you need that port to be opened, you also need it to be forwarded to your computer if you're running behind a NAT router (which almost everyone is).

Comment: when i open 1024:65535 ports, then i can download torrent files, therefore i dont need port forwarding (i think)

Comment: You need port forwarding if you are using NAT, ports and are creating incoming connections to that port.

Answer (score 0):

Is efw a stateful firewall?  If it is, opening up one or two ports (one port per computer if you're behind a NAT) should be sufficient.  Open up both TCP and UDP on those ports just to be safe.  If it's not stateful... then... uh... this might be a bit tougher.  Sorry if I can't be of any more help.